# ffmpeg how make uniq signature video after processing

Tags: ffmpeg

I need to make uniq signature for video file, in this moment i use this command :

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vf scale="1278:trunc(ow/a/2)*2" -r 24 uniq.mp4
```

I this moment i change resolution (1278) and -r framerate 20-30. Exist different solution ? i need solution to make more different files

Comment: It’s not clear what you mean here by “a unique signature”... are you trying to randomly assign different resolutions to different output files? Or something completely differently?

Comment: How are you generating the signature?